# Button Effect OnClick Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a button. The button must be similar to this:

[image]

And when i click to it, it must change in:

[image]

How can i do it? Thanks to all. I need i must use jquery, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example by using Jquery and Css. Hide and Show are used to change the DOM elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#op").hide();
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#result").text(count);
    $("#btn").hide();
    $("#op").show();
  });
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    count++;
    $("#result").text(count);
  });
  $("#minus").click(function() {
    count--;
    $("#result").text(count);
  });
});
```

```css
#btn, .operator{
  background-color:rgb(224,0,0);
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
}

#btn{
  width:50px;
  padding:5px;
}

.operator{
  width:20px;
}

#op{
  width:130px;
}
#op div{
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">click</div>
<div id="op"><div id="minus" class="operator">-</div><div id="result"></div><div id="plus" class="operator">+</div></div>
```

Comment: I don't know why i have created a new page with only your element but when i click on add, nothing happens

Comment: can you create a snippet of the code you are trying?

Comment: Is the same of this. I have copy it in an MVC page and execute. I see correctly the add button but it doens't work when i click

Comment: Have you included the JS file?

Comment: Ok now it works...I don't know why. I only have recreated the object. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Same:

```js
 var value = 0;
  $("#add_btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#add_btn").hide();
    $("#to_show").show();
    value++;
    $("#value").text(value);
  });
  
   $("#minus").on("click", function() {
    value--;
    $("#value").text(value);
  });
  
   $("#plus").on("click", function() {
    value++;
    $("#value").text(value);
  });
```

```css
#to_show {
  display: none;
}
button{
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#value{
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add_btn">Add</button>
<div id="to_show">
  <button id="minus">-</button>
  <div id="value"></div>
  <button id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in javascript.
You might use **jQuery**.

**CSS**

```
.centerButton{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
.smallButton{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

**html**

```
   <div class="centerButton" style="background:#f00;width:50px;height:25px;" id="addButton" >Add</div>
<div style="display:none" id="addButtonExpanded">
        <div  class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left;background:#f00;" id="minusNumber" >-</div>
        <div class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left" id="number" >1</div>
        <div class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left;background:#f00;" id="plusNumber">+</div>

</div>
<input name="numberOfClicksInput" type="hidden" id="numberOfClicksInput"></input>
```

**javascipt**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var numberOfClicks=0;

$("#addButton").click(function() {
    $("#addButton").hide();
    $("#addButtonExpanded").show(); 
    numberOfClicks++;
    $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
});

$("#minusNumber").click(function() {
    numberOfClicks--;
    $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
    if(numberOfClicks==0){
        $("#addButton").show();
        $("#addButtonExpanded").hide();
    } else {
        $("#number").text(numberOfClicks);
    }
})

$("#plusNumber").click(function() {
    numberOfClicks++;
    $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
    $("#number").text(numberOfClicks);
});
 })
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var numberOfClicks=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addButton").click(function(){
 $("#addButton").hide();
 $("#addButtonExpanded").show(); 
 numberOfClicks++;
 $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
});

$("#minusNumber").click(function(){
 numberOfClicks--;
 $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
 if(numberOfClicks==0){
  $("#addButton").show();
  $("#addButtonExpanded").hide();
 }else{
  $("#number").text(numberOfClicks);
 }
})

$("#plusNumber").click(function(){
 numberOfClicks++;
 $("#numberOfClicksInput").val(numberOfClicks);
 $("#number").text(numberOfClicks);
})
});
  })
```

```css
.centerButton{
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
}
.smallButton{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<html>
<head>




<div class="centerButton" style="background:#f00;width:50px;height:25px;" id="addButton" >Add</div>
<div style="display:none" id="addButtonExpanded">
  <div  class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left;background:#f00;" id="minusNumber" >-</div>
  <div class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left" id="number" >1</div>
  <div class="centerButton smallButton" style="float:left;background:#f00;" id="plusNumber">+</div>
  
</div>
<input name="numberOfClicksInput" type="hidden" id="numberOfClicksInput"></input>
```

Comment: I don't know why i have created a new page with only your element but when i click on add, nothing happens